# sticky UILabel on a tableview controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a sticky uilabel on a tableview controller. But unfortunately, it moves with the tableview.

```
func showinvisible() {
        var uzak = CGFloat()
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                uzak = 120
            case 1334:
                uzak = 120
            case 1920, 2208:
                uzak = 120
            case 2436:
                uzak = 250
            default:
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.dynamicLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:screenSize.height - uzak, width:screenSize.width, height:80)
        self.dynamicLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        self.dynamicLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.dynamicLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.dynamicLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("You are currenly invisible", comment: "")
        self.dynamicLabel.font = self.dynamicLabel.font.withSize(12)
        self.view.addSubview(self.dynamicLabel)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.dynamicLabel)
    }
```

I need it to stay at the bottom of the screen. Any idea?

Comment: Try adding it to the window?

Comment: `UITableViewController`'s `view` is a table view, so it's normal that you can't achieve it like this. You can either use a view controller instead or track scrolling and update the labels position.

Comment: @Desdenova Do you think scroll tracking is a good idea?

Comment: try add `self.navigationController.view.addSubview(self.dynamicLabel)`

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Yes, but it’s a bit overkill for the task at hand. I’d go with the view controller approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the label as Navigation Controller view's subview.

```
self.navigationController.view.addSubview(self.dynamicLabel)
```

Comment: I find that the best answer. I need to remove it from superview when did disappear thou but it works.

Comment: Hey you didn't tell you already have a view controller on top of your table view controller.

Comment: While this will work in some cases, as you've found you have to remove the label if the view controller is removed from the nav stack (or if another view controller is pushed on). In iOS development, there's often a quick, easy and potentially fragile way to do it, or there's a way that requires more effort, but long term will be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do this is to use a container view controller. Have a regular `UIViewController` with your label as a subview, and a `UITableViewController` as a child view controller.

This has the added benefit of breaking down a large view controller. You can have logic for fetching data in the parent, for example, and just leave child to handle the presentation.

This is easy to configure in a storyboard…

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a way to do this on a tableview controller.

Comment: When you run the app, the table will appear inside the view controller (i.e. underneath the label) - the label will stay static on top of the table as it is a subview of the parent view controller's view.